# Where are Azerothcore Server Databases Saved (after server has gone live)?

Tags: azerothcore

Where are the Azerothcore Server databases saved once the server is live with characters and changes etc.

I made several versions of the azerothcore folder as I was troubling shooting various modules and each location seems to be tied to the same server databases?
I would like to back up my server and also delete the extra folders.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using MySQL Workbench to export the acore_auth and acore_characters separately as self contained sql files, then re-importing them upon server rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

AzerothCore uses a MySQL/MariaDB database server, containing 3 databases:

- `acore_world` for the world objects (quests, NPCs, etc..) you probably don't want to backup this (instead you should back up your own custom SQL scripts if any, not the entire world)
- `acore_characters` and `acore_auth` respectively, everything related to the **characters** and **accounts**, you do want to have regular backups of them

There are plenty of ways to backup your MySQL/MariaDB database(s) and you can find plenty of tutorials online about how to do it (it's a generic thing, not strictly related to AzerothCore).

You can try this tool as well, which creates backup and automatically sends them to you via Telegram: https://github.com/azerothcore/telegram-automated-db-backup